# When I transform a long expression into fortranform, the output adds a minus sign at every row. How to fix it?

Tags: fortran

I try to transform the following expression into fortranform

```
FortranForm[(1/\[Tau]a)(Cos[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u1[t] + Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u2[t] + Cos[\[Chi]] u3[t]) (-Cos[\[Chi]] u1[t] + Cos[\.[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u3[t]) + 1/\[Tau]c (u1[t]^2 + u2[t]^2 + u3[t]^2) (-u2[t] + Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] (Cos[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u1[t] + Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u2[t] + Cos[\[Chi]] u3[t]))]
```

The output is as follows

```
((Cos(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*u1(t) + Sin(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*u2(t) + Cos(\[Chi])*u3(t))*
 -     (-(Cos(\[Chi])*u1(t)) + Cos(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*u3(t)))/\[Tau]a + 
 -  ((u1(t)**2 + u2(t)**2 + u3(t)**2)*
 -     (-u2(t) + Sin(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*(Cos(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*u1(t) + Sin(\[Eta])*Sin(\[Chi])*u2(t) + Cos(\[Chi])*u3(t))))/\[Tau]c
```

A redundant minus sign appears at each row, how to fix it?

Comment: You're getting a character (a "-" in this case) in column 6 to indicate that this is a continuation line.  See a Fortran IV or Fortran 77 reference (for those of us old enough to know that).

Comment: Oh,I see. I try to use Fortranform + Substitution in Mathematica to transform expressions into python code. For very^3 long expressions, I need to delete all the continuation lines. Now that It is built-in, maybe there doesn't exist a method to delete it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to get rid of the "-" in column 6 is to avoid them right from the start by changing the `PageWidth`:

```
SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> Infinity]
FortranForm[(1/\[Tau]a) (Cos[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u1[t] + 
     Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u2[t] + 
     Cos[\[Chi]] u3[t]) (-Cos[\[Chi]] u1[t] + 
     Cos[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u3[t]) + 
  1/\[Tau]c (u1[t]^2 + u2[t]^2 + u3[t]^2) (-u2[t] + 
     Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] (Cos[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u1[t] + 
        Sin[\[Eta]] Sin[\[Chi]] u2[t] + Cos[\[Chi]] u3[t]))]
SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> 72]
```

This gets you everything on a single line.  Then you can break the result by hand afterwards if necessary.  (But I assume you'll also need to change `χ` to `chi`, etc.)

Comment: It works, thanks! Yes, changing symbols is necessary :)